# Don't think I have php setup right in nginx virtual host configs

Tags: magento, nginx, ubuntu-12.04, php-5.5

I'm trying to install magento php ecommerce on a virtual server that previously did not have php.  When I put simple php pages into a directory they run (for example I have index.php run phpinfo).  But when I try to run the magento setup scripts they bomb out without outputting an error.  I have two other virtual servers through a different service (running apache) and when I drop the magento files into them the setup pages light up right away and start checking requirements.  On my nginx server the only output is a small grey box, but no error output.

My best guess is that I have not configured nginx virtual hosts properly for php.

I am on php5.5 using fpm on Ubuntu 12.04.  I don't run a default file in sites-enabled, just two vhost files.  Here's the vhost in question (the other site is working fine, but it's python):

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
#
        server_name magento.mydomain.com;
#
        root /var/www/magento.mydomain.com/public_html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
#
#       location / {
#               try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php =404;
#       }
#       location / {
#               /index.php;
#       }
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                fastcgi_pass  127.0.0.1:8070;
                fastcgi_index index.php;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/magento.mydomain.com/public_html/$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
}
```

You can see my commented out location / directives.  I have tried those is various fashion.  My hunch was that magento was calling php with directory names only (instead of somedir/index.php) so I was messing with those, but it seems like that would be handled by the index directive before the locations.

I'm pretty green with nginx.  Does anyone see anything obvious?

Comment: There should be logs in `/var/log/nginx` and `/var/log/php-fpm` (unless you configured them in another fashion).  When you send a request to, say, `magento.mydomain.com/index.php` (including magneto scripts) what the logs say?

Comment: It might not be that, since your simple PHP files are running fine. Since nginx doesn't use `.htaccess`, you'll need to convert it to an nginx readable format. [**This**](http://www.anilcetin.com/) site is what I use personally. Drop that into your site config and restart nginx and try again.

Comment: You have an extra `/` in `SCRIPT_FILENAME`, but you should probably use `$document_root$fastcgi_script_name`